# What does the meat reward on the character creation screen do?

Tags: west-of-loathing

When creating a new character, the poster has a meat reward underneath it. Shooting the moving targets to the left increase the amount of meat in this reward.

What does this reward do in the game?

[image: screenshot of character select screen]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't affect anything. The devs have already came out and [said it's just there for fun](http://steamcommunity.com/app/597220/discussions/0/1471967615868790748/). If you keep shooting, you get hints that pop up that will tell you this, as well.

Comment: Do you have a link to where the devs said that? I'll verify the pop up message later tonight

Comment: http://steamcommunity.com/app/597220/discussions/0/1471967615868790748/

Comment: awesome, please include that link in the answer